# Column returns error when called in Select statement, but returns values when * is used

Tags: t-sql, select

Values retrieved for a table column are incorrect unless I use SELECT * FROM table

I'm sure this is something basic that just isn't clicking with me.

Accurate values for the User column are returned when wildcard * is ran against the table, but my SQL Server username replaces the values in the column when it is called in a select statement.  If I try to call the column in the SELECT statement with a table alias, I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

User column is nvarchar(12), Action column is nvarchar(50)

This query returns accurate data in the User column:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransHistory as th
```

This query returns my SQL server username in the User column instead of the actual values:

```
SELECT Action, User
FROM TransHistory
```

This query, using a table alias, results in "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.":

```
SELECT th.Action, th.User
FROM TransHistory as th
```

I expect to get the accurate User ID from the table in all 3 queries.

Comment: Did you try `"User"` or `[User]`  instead?

Comment: "User" does it...man, thanks!  Is it because User is a reserved keyword in SQL or something along those lines?